# Удалённое сообщение при аудите содержит неправильную подсказку на ссылке "Удалить"

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок, аудит

В очереди проверок "Первых сообщений" был пройдет аудит [сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/578295). Сообщение выглядит как обычное (не удалённое), нет бледно-красного фона:

> [image: Подсказка для удаления говорит о восстановлении]

При этом подсказка на ссылке "Удалить" говорит о голосовании за **восстановление**. Если попытаться добавить комментарий, тоже вылезет ошибка о том, что сообщение удалено и комментировать его нельзя.

Если перейти непосредственно к [сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1246074/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c-c-html-css-scss-scc), то можно убедиться, что оно всё же [удалено](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZoom.png).

[Другой аудит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/110474) на удалённом сообщении содержит подсказку консистентную ссылке (по ссылке "Удалить" предлагается голосовать за **удаление**):

> [image: Нормальный аудит на удалённом сообщении]

Стоит заметить, что в проблемном случае - аудит на вопросе, в нормальном - аудит на ответе.

Если кто-то сможет найти нечто подобное на других (лучше всего англоязычных) сайтах, то можно будет оформить багрепорт на MSE.

Comment: Аудит так всегда работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy это уже ПРОЙДЕННЫЙ аудит. В любом случае должна быть консистентность ссылок/тултипов.

Comment: `Если кто-то сможет найти нечто подобное на других (лучше всего англоязычных) сайтах` — сейчас на code golf посмотрю, там правда проверок очень мало ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor чтобы это посмотреть, надо репутацию иметь, достаточную для удаления. А это 20К+ для большинства сайтов.

Comment: Не, там рекомендовать удаление, не то?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ чтобы смотреть удалённые сообщения надо всего 10k репы. В том числе и на enSO

Comment: @Danis так надо не на сообщение смотреть, а на подсказку для "Удалить". Для этого нужно 20К.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ он у меня есть и могу на неё нажать, хотя у меня нету 20k

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, а, я понял.

Comment: @Danis оказалось, что 20К надо для удаления незакрытого вопроса, а для голосования за удаление закрытого действительно должно хватать 10К. Если верить справке.